# User preferences, How can i use loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a question about user preferences

I would like to get the following effect: 
after click "off" - the user does not see the code snippet
after click "on" - the user see the code snippet

currently I have this code (from Internet):

```
//sweetalert
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@8"></script>

//buttons
const offAnimationsButton = $(".offAnimations"),
onAnimationsButton = $(".onAnimations"),

// Events
offAnimationsButton.on("click", () => {localStorage.setItem('animations', 'off');   Swal.fire({
position: 'mid-end',
type: 'error',
title: 'Example Title - ON',
showConfirmButton: false,
width: 850 
}); removeAnimations();});

onAnimationsButton.on("click", () => {localStorage.removeItem('animations', 'off');     Swal.fire({
position: 'mid-end',
type: 'success',
title: 'Example Title - OFF',
showConfirmButton: false,
timer: 2000,
width: 850 
}); location.reload();});

// Functions removing
const removeAnimations = () => {
$(".animated").removeClass("animated"), $(".fas.fa-cog.fa-spin").removeClass("fa-spin")
},

// After page reload checks     
localStorage.getItem("animations")&&removeAnimations();


//On website
<span class="onAnimations">
<i class="fas fa-circle circleON2"></i>
</span>   

<span class="offAnimations">
<i class="far fa-circle circleOFF2"></i>
</span>
```

Alert working, but the content on the site does not change.

It seems to me that here is missing eg "if .. else ..."

How to make this loop for my problem

```
if (xxx == correct) {
<h1> Lorem Ipsum # 1 </h1>
}


else (xxx == incorrect {
<h1> Lorem Ipsum # 1 </h1>
}
```

Thank you in advance for any help: D

Comment: Can somebody help me? :(